# Wordpress: which function is called when user visit /?p=randomstring

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress at the moment return a [random page](https://www.superinformati.com/?p=bdmvxmqa) when visiting, for example, https://www.examplewebsite.com/?p=bdmvxmqa

At the moment it doesn't return a 404 and I'd like to correct it. But I cuouldn't find where to look into the code.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress usually redirects to the closest matching page title. (at least it used to way back when I was working with WordPress).

Try adding this line to functions.php to turn off this feature:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is an old URL structure then you could redirect all ?p requests to your homepage or similar with the below function:

```
  function rusty_redirect_query() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('p');
    if(get_query_var('p')) {
      wp_redirect( home_url( '/page/to/redirect/' ) );
    }
    exit();
  }
  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rusty_redirect_query' );
```